# Using the EXTJS 4 writer.js example - need to create PHP back-end code for CRUD to Oracle DB

Tags: php, oracle, extjs4, crud

I am looking into using the EXTJS 4 writer.js example concept to create an application, but I need to be able to perform all my CRUD operations to a real Oracle database instead of to a SESSION. I am using PHP to perform the CRUD operations instead of to a SESSION variable. Does anyone know what I need to do to write, or can anyone point me in the direction of someone who has done this already, to create the proper back-end code for using PHP to write to a Oracle database using this writer.js example?

Comment: please link to the writer.js example - couldn't see which one you were referring to. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) describes linking.

Comment: Here is a link to the writer.js I am referring to: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/writer/writer.html - As you can see the page uses a PHP back-end to write to the SESSION. I want to be able to write and read to and from a database - MySQL or Oracle.

Comment: I cannot believe that there are no responses, to this question. I even supplied the link to the demo that use the SESSION.